# Topological embedding of a n-skeleton in a n+1 skeleton

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, cw-complexes

I was trying to understand the definition of CW complex which is given in Hatcher Appendix, that is the one given in this previous question: [Understanding Hatcher's definition of CW-complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959916/392807)

In doing that, I was wondering if a n-1 skeleton could be topologically embedded in a n skeleton. More precisely, let $\pi:X^{n−1} \cup \cup_{\alpha} D_{\alpha}^n\rightarrow X^{n}$ be the natural projection and $i:X^{n-1}\rightarrow X^{n−1} \cup \cup_{\alpha} D_{\alpha}^n$ be the inclusion, I was wondering if $\pi\circ i:X^{n-1}\rightarrow X^{n}$ is an homeomorphism on the image(with the subspace topology). I would say yes: it is a right supposition?

If I wasn't mistaken, I showed that is injective and continuous, but I failed in showing for example tha it is open as map on the Image

Thanks for the help

Comment: A topological embedding is not necessarily an open map.

Comment: Sorry, I meant open map on the Image with subpace topology...I edit the post